# async/flow series on node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Consider this code:

```
var async = require('async');

var a = function()
{
    console.log("Hello ");
};
var b = function()
{
    console.log("World");
};


async.series(
[
    a,b
]
    );
```

Output is 
`Hello`

Why is `World` not part of the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each method called in `series` it is passed a callback method which must be run, which you are ignoring in your example.

[The docs say](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback):

> tasks - An array or object containing functions to run, each function
>   is passed a callback(err, result) it must call on completion with an
>   error err (which can be null) and an optional result value.

The reason why your code is stopping after the first method is that the callback isn't being run, and `series` assumed an error occurred and stopped running.

To fix this, you have to rewrite each method along these lines:

```
var b = function(callback)
{
    console.log("World");
    callback(null, null) // error, errorValue
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) function passes one callback to each of the methods that must be called before the next one is called. If you change your functions `a` and `b` to call the function it will work.

```
function a(done){
    console.log('hello');
    done(null, null); // err, value
}


function b(done){
    console.log('world');
    done(null, null); // err, value
}
```